# Magento 1.9 Programatically Updating Cart Returns all products updated at the same time

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently making our site have an ajax add, remove, update all through ajax for the cart.

Part of my add to cart function:

```
if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {

                if($_GET['superAttributes'] != 'false') {

                    $options = array();
                    $superAtts = json_decode($_GET['superAttributes']);
                    $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);

                    foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
                        foreach ($superAtts as $att) {
                            if($att[0] == 'attribute'.$productAttribute['attribute_id']) {
                                $options[$productAttribute['attribute_id']] = $att[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $params = new Varien_Object([
                        'qty' => (int)$qty,
                        'super_attribute' => $options
                    ]);

                    $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $params);

                }

            } else {

                $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product,(int)$qty);

            }

$quote->collectTotals()->save();


            $outputArray = $this->returnFormattedData($product, $quote, $qty, $quoteItem, $originalSetOfSkus);


            $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader(
                'Content-type',
                'application/json'
            );
            // Set the response body / contents to be the JSON data
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(
                Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($outputArray)
            );
```

Once this is done i return an updated cart

```
$outputArray = [
            'products' => [],
            'taxDifferent'  => '£' .number_format($taxAmount, 2),
            'cartTotalCount' => $quote2->getItemsQty(),
            'subTotal'  => '£' .number_format($subTotal, 2),
            'grandTotal' => '£' .number_format($grandTotal, 2),
            'discountTotal' => number_format($discountTotal, 2)
        ];



        $arrayOutput = [];

        $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $items = $quote2->getItemsCollection(true)->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');

        foreach ($items as $_item) {

            if($removeFromCart) {
                if($_item->getSku() == $_GET['sku']) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $prodImages = [];

            $productHere = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());

            foreach ($productHere->getMediaGalleryImages() as $key => $image) {
                $string = $image->getData()['url'];
                array_push($prodImages, $string);
            }

            $productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")
                ->loadByProduct($_item->getProduct()->getId());


            $priceOverride = false;

            if(count($_item->getProduct()->getTierPrice()) > 0) {
                foreach (array_reverse($_item->getProduct()->getTierPrice()) as $priceTier) {
                    $qtyCheck = (int)number_format($priceTier['price_qty'],0);
                    if($_item->getQty() >= $qtyCheck)
                    {
                        $priceOverride =  number_format($priceTier['price'],2);
                    } else {
                        $priceOverride =  number_format($_item->getPrice(),2);
                    }
                }
            }

            $quantiySelector = true;

            if($priceOverride !== false) {
                $price = '£' . $priceOverride;
            } elseif ($_item->getPrice() == 0){

                $quote2->getAppliedRuleIds();
                $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($quote2->getAppliedRuleIds());
                $price = (count($rule->getStoreLabels()) > 0) ? '<span class="bottom">' . $rule->getStoreLabels()[0] . '</span>' :'FREE';

            } else {
                $price = '£' . number_format($_item->getPrice(),2);
            }

            if($price == '£0.00') {
                $quote2->getAppliedRuleIds();
                $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($quote2->getAppliedRuleIds());
                $price = (count($rule->getStoreLabels()) > 0) ? '<span class=bottom">' . $rule->getStoreLabels()[0] . '</span>' :'FREE';
                $quantiySelector = false;
            }


            if($_item->getProduct()->getPrice() > $_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()) {



                $price = '<span class="old-price" style="text-decoration: line-through; color: lightgrey;padding-right: 5px;">

                    £' . number_format($_item->getProduct()->getPrice(), 2) . '
            </span>


            <span class="regular-price" style="color: #E62746 !important; ">
                    £' . number_format($_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(), 2) . '            </span>';

            }

            $isConfigProduct = ($_item->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'configurable');

            $newName = false;

            if($isConfigProduct) {

                $newName = '';

                $attributes = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectedAttributesInfo($_item->getProduct());
                $count = 1;
                $newName .= $_item->getName();

                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

                    $newName .= ' '.$attribute['value'];

                    if($count == count($attributes)) {
                        $newName .= '';
                    } else {
                        $newName .= ' ';
                    }

                    $count++;

                }

                $price = '£' . number_format($_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(),2);
            }

            $updated = false;
            if($_item->getSku() == $_GET['sku']) {
                $updated = new DateTime();
            }

            $arrayOutput[] = [
                'quoteId' => $_item->getId(),
                'sku'   => $_item->getSku(),
                'qty'   => $_item->getQty(),
                'price' =>  $price,
                'product_image' =>  array_values($prodImages),
                'name'  => ($newName != false) ? $newName : $_item->getName(),
                'cartTotalCount' => $quote2->getItemsQty(),
                'uniqueProducts' => $quote2->getItemsCount(),
                'grandTotal' => '£' .number_format($grandTotal, 2),
                'subTotal'  => '£' .number_format($subTotal, 2),
                'taxDifferent'  => '£' .number_format($taxAmount, 2),
                'discountTotal' => number_format($discountTotal, 2),
                'maxQuantityAllowed' => ($_item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() == $_item->getQty()),
                'maxQuant' => $productQuantity->getMaxSaleQty(),
                'prodUrl' => $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(),
                'removeDisabledAttr' => ($Updated > 1),
                'maxQty' => $productQuantity->getMaxSaleQty(),
                'showQuantitySelect' => $quantiySelector,
                'updatedAt' => ($updated != false) ? $updated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : $_item->getUpdatedAt()
            ];
        }

        function date_compare($a, $b)
        {
            $t1 = strtotime($a['updatedAt']);
            $t2 = strtotime($b['updatedAt']);
            return $t2 - $t1;
        }
        usort($arrayOutput, 'date_compare');


        $outputArray['products'] = $arrayOutput;

        return $outputArray;
```

The issue that i am facing is when add one item or update quantity... the return response is saying that 3 of the 6 items would be updated at exactly the same time so the cart is getting returned in a random order not at which was updated last?